# My script doesn't extract all the ads details and I'm not getting the right numbers

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, google-bigquery

I'm using the facebook marketing API to extract my ads details and then store them on Google BigQuery but apparently my script does ignore some ad sets and I didn't find a way to fix it ! Here is my code:

Find below my python script:

```
`for delta in range(1000)[20:28]:

  process_date = (datetime.datetime.today()+datetime.timedelta(days=-delta)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  date_compact = process_date.replace('-', '')
  print('processing date %s, delta %s' % (process_date, delta))

  params['time_range']['since'] = process_date
  params['time_range']['until'] = process_date

  stats = AdAccount(ad_account_id).get_insights(
    fields=fields,
    params=params,
  )


  ad_list = list()
  for ad_insight in stats:
    ad_list.append(ad_insight)
  storage_client = storage.Client(project='project')
  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('project')
  blob = bucket.blob('fb/fb_%s.csv' % date_compact)

  header_line = ','.join(['date']+fields)
  content_lines = [header_line]
  for ad in ad_list:
    ad_line = ','.join([process_date]+['"%s"'%str(ad[field].encode('latin9').decode('latin9')).replace('"', "'") for field in fields])
    content_lines.append(ad_line)
  blob.upload_from_string('\n'.join(content_lines))

  bq_client = bigquery.Client(project='project')
  job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
  job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
  job_config.field_delimiter = ','
  job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
  job_config.source_format = 'CSV'

  schema = [bigquery.schema.SchemaField(name=field, field_type='STRING') for field in ['date']+fields]
  job_config.schema = schema

  dataset_id = '2_digital'
  destination_table = 'fb_ad_stats_%s' % date_compact
  table_ref = bq_client.dataset(dataset_id).table(destination_table)
  result = bq_client.load_table_from_uri(source_uris='gs://project/fb/fb_%s.csv'%date_compact, destination=table_ref, job_config=job_config).result()
```

What I'm expecting as a result is all the ads and campaigns with all the details (number of clicks, impressions and spend )

Comment: It is unclear what it missing. Missing a few rows? Missing couple or column? Missing some column from some rows?

Comment: Missing some ad set from some campaigns.. means I'm missing a bunch of rows

Comment: I would try to debug one day of data, starting from dumping unique keys and compare with what is stored in BigQuery. Looking at rows which were failed to insert to see why they failed.